# I'm getting error io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source) in Infogix Data360 application

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting the below error in `Infogix Data360` application which is deployed on AWS.

`java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source).`

Please help me to understand what kind of issue it is ,and how can I come out from this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Now I get to know the solution of this issue ,Initially I have chosen shared cluster -small. After changing shared cluster from Small to Medium issue get resolved.
This might help you all.